# Hibernate + Spring: Conditional on create bean validation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, rest, validation

I use the date validaton using the [@Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/validation/constraints/Future.html) annotation.

```
@NotNull
@DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
@Column(name = "FROM")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Future
private Date from;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "FOO")
private String foo;
```

I perform CRUD operations using Rest API. The requirement is the `from` date will be in future - after the entity is being created (today). However, the time changes and in case of changing the field `foo` using ex. PUT method, the validation won't pass.

```
@PutMapping(value = "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> put(
    @Valid @RequestBody MyEntity myEntity, 
    @PathVariable("id") int id) 
{
    ... update entity based on id
}
```

When I call this method in the far future (after the `from` value persisted), the validation doesn't let me perform the operation, because the field `from` is no more valid.

There is a simple in-built solution to trigger a certain validation only on create event?

I have been thinking over creating the own cross-field validation through annotation, however I am not able to determine the creation based on other fields.

Comment: What's the relation between changing `foo` field and making `from` field invalid ?

Comment: I have described it. The field `from` must be in the future (let's say I set 2 days onward). After one week, I decide to use PUT method and change `foo` or another field, but the @Future condition won't pass, because in one week, ithe field `from` will be actually in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Grouping Constraints](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-groups.html#chapter-groups), to restrict which validation set to use for: `pre-persist`, `pre-update`, `pre-remove` and `ddl`(For database schema).

So to validate `from` field just for persist operation and ignore it for put(update), you may:

Add an interface e.g. `GroupFuture`:

```
package com.example.entity;

public interface GroupFuture {}
```

In your `MyEntity`, I think you should also add [@NotNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html) constraint as `@Future` consider `null` as valid value:

```
//...
//Maybe @NotNull
@Future(groups = GroupFuture.class)
private Date from;

//...
```

Finally, if you've configured hibernate using:
`persistence.xml`, add this line in the `persistence-unit` setting:

```
<property name="javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist" value="javax.validation.groups.Default, com.example.GroupFuture">
```

Programmatically:

```
// If you're using pure hibernate
Configuration configuration = new Configuration().setProperty("javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist", javax.validation.groups.Default, com.example.GroupFuture);
```

`

```
// If you're using JPA/hibernate
entityManagerFactory.getJpaPropertyMap().put("javax.persistence.validation.group.pre-persist", javax.validation.groups.Default, com.example.GroupFuture);
```

Useful reading(even it's for hibernate 3.6): [Chapter 23. Additional modules](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/NotNull.html)

Comment: Thank you, I'll give it a try.